# How to only add something to value in a map?

Tags: java

I have a treemap, with a string as key and a treeset as value. I've already added my keys without adding any values. So I have a map with keys and empty set as value. I want to add elements to my empty set later in my code. How do I do that?

```
for (String type : alltypes) { //alltypes is a set with types
    TreeSet<String> words = new TreeSet<String>(); //creating list of anagrams
    anagram.put(type,words); //words is an empty set
}
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : allewords.entrySet()) {
    String word = entry.getKey();
    String types= entry.getValue();
    if(anagram.containsKey(types)) {
        // add elements(String word) to set words
    }
```

This code is a part of an anagram program. `alltypes` contains all the sortedletter versions of the words of my input. `allwords` contains the normal word as key and the sorted version as value. In the end I want to have a map with the sortedletter as key and the words which have the same sortedletters (aka anagrams) as a list stored in value.

Comment: This Question is confusing. Have you stripped down to focus on the core of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
      anagram.get(key)//now you have reference to your set
      .add(value); //add your value
```

Comment: .add(value)? that does not work:(
do I have to put something in front of the dot?

Comment: your value here is types , so .add(types)

Comment: the value i want to add is actually word, but .add(word) does not work?

Answer (score 0):

the way to do it is anagram.get(types).add(word)